# %in% and subset return wrong results for a particular value in vectors in data frames

Tags: r

A bizzarre behavior I just observed in R.

Started with:

```
d <- data.frame(x = rep(seq(1, 20, 0.2), 10))
subset(d, d$x == 17.4)
```

which returns nothing, even though 17.4 is clearly in the data frame. Same happens for 18.4 as well, and a few other values.

Same thing for:

```
x <- seq(1, 20, 0.2)
print(17.4 %in% x)
```

returns FALSE.

Checked on ideone.com, so no problem with my interpreter or anything.

Interestingly, if 17.4 is treated as a string, so do

```
"17.4" %in% x
```

that returns TRUE.

In this case x[83] is 17.4 and both str(x[83]) and str(17.4) are of course 'num', but:

```
x[83] == 17.4
```

returns FALSE.

I'm super baffled at what this small thing is about.

Comment: Seems like a case for [Why are these numbers not equal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal)

Comment: @TheScientist5914: you should read the rest of the R-FAQ as well.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! So the conclusion is that subsetting a data frame with a logical == is dangerous and shouldn't be done then? Quick search on Google shows me a number of places show such examples, which makes me uneasy given this example.